# Can the weapon summoned via a Warlock's Pact of the Blade be pre-silvered when summoned?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, weapons, warlock, special-materials

### Would it be possible to manifest a weapon that has either the Silvered or the Adamantine property?

Per the description of *Pact of the Blade*:

> You can use your action to create a pact weapon in your empty hand. You can choose the form that this melee weapon takes each time you create it (see chapter 5 for weapon options).

Chapter 5 in the Players Handbook is about Equipment; including Weapons. Within weapons there is a subsection on Silvered Weapons.

> Some monsters that have immunity or resistance to nonmagical weapons are susceptible to silver weapons, so cautious adventurers invest extra coin to plate their weapons with silver. You can silver a single weapon or ten pieces of ammunition for 100 gp. This cost represents not only the price of the silver, but the time and expertise needed to add silver to the weapon without making it less effective.

If this was a physical thing, then it would require spending money for the silvering process. But this is a weapon created from the mind of the wielder and formed from Shadow.

Note: I understand that silvering a weapon is used to overcome resistance and the manifested weapon is considered magical which generally overcomes the same resistance. But I could envision a monster that is actually vulnerable to silver so silvering it would be a boon beyond just being magical.

Also, if a weapon has the Adamantine property it becomes better at breaking objects. Another bonus above just being magical.

Comment: I gave my answer, but as to your comments at the bonus received from "silvering weapons" or "weapons made of adamatine". I suggest you have this physical weapon made for you, then have it "common" magically enchanted with a "quirk", I suggest the "inheritor background" "candle light" (its basically "lesser moon-touched"), then "transform it" into your pack weapon (PHB pg 108)

Comment: Thank you @JeffreyWitty, but you don't need to comment every time that you leave an answer.

Comment: Related: [Can a Pact of the Blade warlock summon any weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/202041/33569)

Answer (score 16):

### No, as silvered and adamantine weapons are not items that are directly mentioned in chapter 5

You have already quoted the relevant section, which states that you have to see chapter 5 for your weapon options. Within chapter 5 it describes the ability to silver weapons, but does not specify any particular silvered weapons. It does not even mention adamantine weaponry. As such, only the mundane weapons are permitted.

Comment: ...does it actually say that you have to take weapon options from chapter 5?  I wouldn't necessarily read it that way.  For instance, other sources with weapons in.

Comment: @Stackstuck What I take the excerpt to mean is that the options which are valid are in chapter 5, and any others may be allowed by the DM if they choose. It's also from a balance perspective that I have chosen this answer, which I guess I should add. Regardless of other balance thoughts, giving 500 gp to a character for a class feature is a bit too powerful for my liking.

Comment: it doesnt say "make choice only from" it says "see chapter 5 FOR OPTIONS". But that being said I think there are 2 weapons not like this, the double-bladed scimitar & boomerang (and boomerang has no mundane entry at all). Is this a neat issue, a twitter comment from WotC on pact weapon "limits" would be awesome

Comment: See this related Q&A regarding whether the possible weapons created by the feature are limited to the weapons in the Weapons table: [Can a Pact of the Blade warlock summon any weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/202041/33569)

Answer (score 4):

The players hand book refers to Chapter 11 for lists of spells for each class in exactly the same way and in exactly the same words that Pact of the blade refers you to Chapter 5,

The only mention of Adamantine Weapons is in Xanathar's Guide to Everything, This is the same book that contains the lists of extra spells that are allowed on practically every game table.

It clearly states that Adamantine, whilst rare, is completly natural, it states its effect and its cost. IT IS NOT MAGICAL (see XGTE page78)

I see no way to disallow an Adamantine weapon being created by Pact of the Blade without also disallowing all spells contained in Xanathar's Guide to Everything

As stated previously, even though the previous post was clearly in error, it is clearly written in the book with rock solid precedence on the interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

### No, it's just the base weapon with no additional properties.

The pact weapon conjured using the Pact of the Blade feature can't have an "additional" property, like being "moon-touched" or "silvered". It can only 100% mimic the standard weapon, with its listed properties of that weapon plus that of the pact weapon. So Silvered or Adamantine versions of weapons, which have no printed listings, can't be used.

That being said, the pact weapon is considered "magical", so **the benefit of being silvered is mostly moot**.

It could be a *Double-Bladed Scimitar* in the Forgotten Realms setting (only as a pact weapon), or any other printed standard weapon, even though that's not listed in chapter 5 of PHB (it doesn't say "*limited to* options in chapter 5"; it only says to see chapter 5 for options - like how some spells aren't listed in PHB chapter 11; it doesn't forbid them from use because PHB says spells are found in PHB chapter 11). But there are no entries in sources for specific "silvered/adamantine" weapons (it's only a separate, addable property).

**Any weapon** (listed in PHB chapter 5 or not) is legal by RAW, but it needs an entry in an official source to be RAW allowed (it needs to "exist").

So yes, you could conjure a weapon that doesn't otherwise exist in the campaign setting, but not add a property. You have *at least* 4 "best" choices (a Glaive or Halberd for 1d10 + reach, or Greatsword or Maul for 2d6).

But no, **you can *never* add an "extra" property not found on the standard "version" of the weapon to your pact weapon "version" of it** (other than the pact weapon's listed bonuses).

I gave my answer, but **as to your comments**: the additional bonus received from "silvering weapons" or "weapons made of adamantine", PLUS the ability to summon it to your hand.  All can be solved "in one" as I detail below:

I suggest you have this physical "Silvered Adamantine Weapon"  made for you:

1. Have this physical "Silvered Adamantine Weapon"  made for you (weapons base cost + 500gp to be made of adamantine + 100gp to silver weapon, MAX = 650gp for Greatsword)
2. Then have it "common" magically enchanted with a "quirk", I suggest
   the "inheritor background's candle light *quirk*," ([SEE HERE](https://dndadventurersleague.org/the-sword-coast-adventurers-guide-and-you/):
   its basically "lesser moon-touched")
3. Then "transform it" into your pact weapon (PHB pg 108).

This should be very cheap (when considering its stacked benefits):

1. Base item cost + (1d6+1) x10 = "X'gp (Note: this is using FULL "Common" cost, "Quirk" should be 50% this, imho. But I do not know of RAW pricing for "quirks")
2. "X"gp + 100gp & 1 week down time = TOTAL

Therefore: **BASE ITEM COST + 120 to 170gp & 1 week downtime (MAX 770 gp to 820 gp)**

"Base item cost" is where the cost of your choose "Silvered Adamantine Weapon" is inserted (allowing you all the bonuses in 1 weapon, bundled with its own "pocket dimension" to store it in lol)

applicable part of link:

> "If you wish your item to have minor magic quirk, you may choose to either have your inheritance glow with the light of a candle [..]"

Comment: to whoever edits my posts formatting/grammar, you are just golden! I wish that I was as well written as yourself.