# Can a warlock with Pact of the Blade bind a non-magical weapon to be their pact weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, weapons, warlock

In the warlock's Pact of the Blade feature description, it states the following:

> ... You can transform one magic weapon into your pact weapon by performing a special ritual while you hold the weapon. ...

This indicates to me that *only* magical weapons can be bound in this way. Does that mean a silvered weapon, adamantine weapon, or even just a entirely mundane weapon is unable to be bound in this manner?

(My question was inspired by [this question about summoning a pact weapon that's already silvered.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138195/45088))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Going by RAW, you are correct: only magic weapons

The part you're quoting from the PHB indicates that magical weapons can be bound like this. Also backed up in [Sage Advice](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/06/25/can-a-blade-pact-warlock-use-the-weapon-ritual-on-a-non-magic-weapon/).

So unless the silvered/adamantine weapon is magical, you can't bind it as your pact weapon. As for mundane, you can create them using the Pact of the Blade feature, as described in the PHB:

> You can use your action to create a pact weapon in your
>   empty hand. You can choose the form that this melee
>   weapon takes each time you create it (see chapter 5 for
>   weapon options).

Comment: So does this mean that you could create an adamantine/silvered/whatever weapon as your pact weapon?

Comment: @Stackstuck this is room for debate as silvered weapons are mentioned in chapter 5, but many answers online have stated it's best discussed with your DM. Since adamantine isn't mentioned in chapter 5, I'd rule you can't conjure an adamantine pact weapon

Comment: Just to add to this question, only melee weapons can be summoned using the normal summon, but any weapon can be used as the 'magical' pact weapon. This includes bows, crossbows, nets, hand crossbows etc. without needing the Improved Pact Weapon evocation.

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes, only magical weapons qualify for this feature (PHB p.108).

The feature is further explained in the [v2.2 Sage Advice](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf), where it is again stated that the weapon *has* to be magical.

Using the RAF (Rules as Fun) approach, I would probably allow any weapon with even the slightest enchantment to be considered magical for the purpose of that feature.