# Can a Pact of the Blade warlock summon any weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, weapons, warlock, summoning

With the Blade boon, can a warlock summon *any* weapon, or does it have to be from the Weapons table?

If it has to be a weapon from the Weapons table, can you do things like change the weight?

Comment: Highly related: [Can the weapon summoned via a Warlock's Pact of the Blade be pre-silvered when summoned?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138195)

Comment: Define any. Are you looking for a nuke? An anti-matter rifle?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Ask your DM.

The text of the class feature just tells you to consult the weapons table for options:

> You can choose the form that this melee weapon takes each time you create it (see the Weapons section for weapon options).

It doesn't say "the only weapon options" or "the options available for this feature". It just says options. The language doesn't tell us that you can't make other weapons or modify existing ones, but it doesn't tell you that you can either. You will have to ask your DM.

That said, if a player is not changing mechanics and is going for flavor, I'll generally allow just about anything you can come up with to make your character as cool as you want. But if you are changing mechanics, for example, [as this question asks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138195/62294), trying to get a silvered or adamantine weapon, I am going to defer to the weapons table.

Comment: *technically* speaking, any ranged weapon that's not a light/heavy crossbow, shortbow, or longbow is off-limits by RAW, thanks to the specific wording of the Improved Pact Weapon invocation. that's the only RAW exception I can see, though.

Comment: I'll point out that there are melee weapon options that aren't in the PHB weapon table, like the elven double-bladed sword from the Eberron book, or the Zulu spear in Tomb of Annihilation.

Answer (score 18):

### Your weapon options are limited

The Pact of the Blade feature states:

> You can use your action to create a pact weapon **in your empty hand**. You can choose the form that this **melee weapon** takes each time you create it (see chapter 5 for weapon options). You are proficient with it while you wield it.

So, this cannot be any weapon. It must be:

- a melee weapon
- fit into your hand, so no oversized weapons (giant versions, or such)

There is an Improved Pact Weapon eldritch invocation for Hexblade warlocks that (among other benefits) extends this to:

> Finally, the weapon you conjure can be a shortbow, longbow, light crossbow, or heavy crossbow.

My reading of *see chapter 5 for weapon options* [differs slightly from Thomas'](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/202042/75095). I think that you would be limited to the weapons in chapter 5:

- The word **option** already contains a scope, meaning "a thing that is or may be chosen", so the weapons from chapter 5 are those things that may be chosen.
- While the feature does not explicitly say these options are your only options, the feature does not direct you to other weapons in the DMG (e.g. for modern weapons), only to those in chapter 5<sup>1</sup>

The Sage Advice Compendium confirms this with an explicit answer (emphasis added):

> The warlock’s Pact of the Blade feature (PH, 107–8) lets you
> create a melee weapon out of nothing. Whenever you do
> so, you determine the weapon’s form, **choosing from the
> melee weapon options in the Weapons table in the Player’s
> Handbook (p. 149)**.

#### Can you modify the weapon stats?

As you only can pick a weapon from the table, you cannot. There also is an internal logic to the weapon table, balancing cost, weight, damage and properties such as light, heavy and two-handed. Modified weapons that do not use these combinations run some risk of being unbalanced.

In any case, using stats not in the book would be homebrew<sup>2</sup>, and as such would need your DMs OK to introduce to the game to begin with, so if you are bound to the table or not does not really matter: if you want to get around some of the limitations, you need DM buy-in either way.

---

<sup>1</sup> There may be several reasons for this, one that the DMG is not intended to be player facing. Two, that at the time of the first printing of the PHB in August 2014, there was no DMG, the DMG did not get published until November that year. The PHB has been reprinted since then, and errata have not updated this.

<sup>2</sup> Note that even the DMG, while containing guidance on how to develop monsters, races, traps, spells, NPCs, backgrounds, magic items and even modifying classes, does not have advice on how to make new weapons. The only advice is on page 41, to reflavor exisiting weapons for other settings, so instead of coming up with stats for a katana, use longsword stats and *call it* a katana.

Comment: There is a small hiccough regarding directing players to references outside of Chapter 5. At the time of the first printing, there **were no other references**. The PHB came out in [August 2014](https://dungeonsdragons.fandom.com/wiki/Player%27s_Handbook_(5e)), but the DMG did not get published until [November 2014](https://dungeonsdragons.fandom.com/wiki/Dungeon_Master%27s_Guide_(5e)). Now, PHB has been reprinted since then, and erratas have not updated this. But the theory of not being directed elsewhere loses some credibility since there was nothing else to reference at the time.

Comment: Good answer; I think it may also be relevant to quote the text from the books where it suggests simulating other weapons using the stats from the main table? eg if a player wants to have a katana, they can just use a longsword and describe it as a katana. That strongly suggests that the weapons table is meant to be exhaustive.

Comment: Also the answer to the question about making a magical ranged weapon your Pact Weapon in the Sage Advice Compendium confirms the intent is that you only choose from the melee weapons table.

Comment: @GuybrushMcKenzie Thank you -- that makes the case pretty clear. I added a section for it.